# Gitlab security-code-scan-sast unable to build project from solution file using `nuget and `msbuild`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, sast

We have been trying to implement Gitlab SAST in our Gitlab CI/CD pipelines.

When the pipeline runs, it triggers the **security-code-scan-sast** job and it returns an error in building the solution file like this:

```
[FATA] [security-code-scan] [2023-05-11T06:17:39Z] ▶ Unable to build project from solution file using `nuget and `msbuild`.
output: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
/this/is/path/to/Project.dtproj(3,3): error MSB4067: The element <DeploymentModel> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the possible solution?

Any idea is much appreciated.